# How to allow access to a folder that's not in my website directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

On my server I have a folder storing mp3 music files in `C:\music`
My website directory is in another folder say `C:\Destop\myWebsite`

I want to allow people to download mp3 from `C:\music\mySong.mp3`, what's the best way to achieve this?

A solution I come up with is to have an end point say `www.myWebsite.com/getMp3`, then in the `getMp3Controller` I can fetch the mp3 then return it. Is this the correct solution? Also if I do it this way, it seems I'm loading the mp3 file twice: first into the controller then send it to visitor. But this seems quite unnecessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a virtual directory on the website that points to your directory with the  mp3 files, and then in your website you can link to files in the virtual directory.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, perhaps you could flesh it out with some details?

Answer (score 1):

As Tony mentioned in his post, you want to create a virtual directory under your application in IIS and point that directory to your music folder. Your suggestion to have a controller grab the file is ok, but it tried up a thread in your app pool that can be better handled by IIS using the core IIS functionality to serve files.

It will also be important that the web user has the appropriate permission, through IIS and through the underlying file system, to access this folder. Depending on the version of IIS and your computer, this could be IUSR_[computername] or ASP.NET Worker Process or Network Service. Check to see what the app pool runs under.

Last bit of advice, as a warning. Opening your computer up to allow people to download MP3 files can have security and legal consequences, and affect the performance of your computer. Choose wisely.